# Get All jcomponents and their location on a jframe

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I want a jframe on which i am adding jcomponents dynamically and on a button click i want to know about all the available components and their location(or sequence).
I am using this method

```
Component[] components=getContentPane().getComponents();
            components.toString();
```

but i am getting a string which contain too much info about components I only need their names(not must variable name their class name means JLabel lbl; so I want JLabel )
and their sequence.

It don't know how to extract this info from the string.

Comment: Unless you are giving the `Component`s you are adding a name, via the `setName` method, the `Component`s will have no name.  You ascertain their type by using `instanceof` (ie `if (comp instanceof JLabel){...`), but then you'd have to guess which component it actually was.  As to there location, you can use `getLocation`...

Comment: but these are for single component.
i have to call getLocation() method for every component which i cant because i don't know how many components will be there.they are generated dynamically

Comment: Use a `for-loop` to loop over the `Component[]` array...really...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All components have a `getLocation` method, simply take your array of components and loop over them...

```
for (Component comp : getContentPane().getComponents()) {
    System.out.println(comp.getLocation());
}
```

The `getLocation` method will return a `java.awt.Point` which contains the x/y coordinates of the component.

Remember, `getComponents` will only return the components within the immediate container, it does not do a recursive search on it's own...